# Add new node to existed CouchDB cluster after cluster_finished

Tags: couchdb, cluster-computing

Can I add new node to an existed CouchDB cluster?

Basically, I already completed a CouchDB cluster configuration using /_cluster_setup API, with finish_cluster action. Can I still add another new node to the cluster manually using CouchDB REST API? I tried to use /_cluster_setup API again to add it, but the new node is not included in "all_nodes" section from /_memebership API.

I also tried to follow the example on http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/cluster/nodes.html#adding-a-node . But it seems not helping.

Any recommendation?